# Report All Files Hierarchically on a Zip-of-Zip Files from the Command-Line Interface

Tags: command-line, zip, winzip

I have a `WinZip` parent file that contains hundreds of WinZip child files on a Windows 7 64-bit computer.  Each child WinZip file has many "grandchild" files within it.  I need to create a text file non-verbose report of all the exploded files:  the child files, and the grandchildren files within each child.

Using the command-line (Version 4.0 64-bit [Build 10562]), one can create a text report of the children files, but not the embedded files within each child:

```
wzzip /vb MyFileFamily.zip > MyFileFamilyReport.txt
```

The WinZip tool or the `command-line interface` both offer ways to report the child files, but not the embedded files additionally.  How do you create a full report of *all* the files within the zip-of-zips from the command-line?

Comment: How is this a poor question?  I hesitate to even post questions here anymore because of the rude way some are downgraded without comment.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. However, SO is not a place where you can ask for a task to be done, or opinions on how to get id done, as this make a question too broad (and downvoted - closed). Instead I recommend you to post the code you've been working on to solve this, and then somebody may help you clear any errors or malfunctions it could have.

Comment: I'm not asking for the task to be done, just looking for a pointer on this.  I've posted the command already.

Comment: Still I'm unable to see how does this question involves programming. That's what SO is intended for... This is more a general software question.

Comment: Cristian, is that narrow enough for you?  How about removing your down-votes?

Comment: Cristian, not everything on SO is structured programming:  take a look at command-line, batch-file, or WinZip tags and you'll realize this.

Comment: Just one downvote is mine and I made my point. The other downvote owner did not comment. If you check the questions on the Winzip tag, almost all of them are closed as they are as broad as this one, and not involving programming. And if still you have any doubts, feel free to check the On-topic section of the help section: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.. just to help you out on this, I've found these 3 approaches

[arkfind](https://github.com/detly/arkfind) : You will need to install Python to run this, but seems to do exactly what you need.

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16645440/2216414) to a similar question. Runs on Linux/perl, so it might work as well with some little tweaks

And finally [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/770270), needs PowerShell, and it uses 7-zip instead of WinZip, but I think it should be easy to change to your needs

I hope one of these helps you out